# PHP code -need to reaffirm basic scope knowledge

Tags: php, scope, closures

consider this code:

```
$a = 2;
function foo(){
    $a = 3;
    return $a;
}
$a = foo();
echo $a;
```

The answer is `echo $a == 3`.

Please correct me if i'm wrong:

As function `foo()` was re-assigned into the global `$a`, it made `$a` from `foo()` scope change it's closure into the global scope rendering `$a` as 3?

Would that be the right answer for this?

Comment: Probably... Are you doing your homework using stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

There are no closures in your code. Period. PHP is pass (and return) by value. There are also only two variable scopes in PHP: global and local.

```
$a = 2; // global scope
function foo() {
    $a = 3; // local variable scope
    return $a;   // return value of local variable to calling context
}
$a = foo(); // assign value returned from function to $a
```

Consider this alternative:

```
$a = 1; 
$b = 10;

function foo() {
    echo $a, $b; // warning: undefined variable on both "a" and "b"
    global $a;   // "import" $a in the local scope
    echo $a, $b; // output "1" for a, and undef var. warning for "b" again
    $a = 2;      // changes the global value
    $b = 20;     // local-only change
    echo $a, $b; // output "2" and "20"
}
echo $a, $b; // "1" and "10"
foo();
echo $a, $b; // "2" and "10": b was local-only, so did not get changed globally in the function
```